# Angular - How to display element and sort with a checkbox using an API

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to use a checkbox in order to display elements in a table that has got the status set as "error" within the return of the json API call.

The Json send me back something like this, with nested elements:

```json
{
  "type": "firstEl",
  "firstTeam": {
    "date": "2020-10-14T14:36:12.859Z",
    "item": {
      "organizationCode": "THUG",
      "status": "success"
    },
    "secondTeam": {
      "date": "2020-10-14T14:36:12.859Z",
      "item": {
        "organizationCode": "THUG",
        "status": "success"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to make something like this with no success so far (nothing sorted) :

TS :

```js
onlyError = false;
    
selectErrors() {
  this.onlyError = !this.onlyError;
}
```

HTML :

```html
<div class="custom" (click)="selectErrors()" style="width:150px">
    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="onlyError">
    <label container="body">
        <div class="content">
            <div>Only error</div>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>

...

<tr *ngFor="let property of property$ | async " class="row">
  <td class="cell">
      <div class="u-font--bold u-pointer d-flex justify-content-between">
          {{property.firstTeam.item.status}}
      </div>
  </td>
  <td class="cell">
      <div class="u-font--bold u-pointer d-flex justify-content-between">
          {{property.secondTeam.item.status}}
      </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I have tried many things, such as making something like this within the service :

```js
transform(error: boolean) {
    return myApiUrl.filter(l => {
        let keep = true;

        if (!error) {
            keep = l.firstTeam.status === 'success' || _.get(l, 'secondTeam.status', '') === 'success' 
        } else {
            keep = l.firstTeam.status === 'error' || _.get(l, 'secondTeam.status', '') === 'error'
        }

        return keep;
    });
}
```

with no success. I am trying to get the simpliest approach to got my data filtered on the status, when a team received one, and to be able to display only the teams with an error message.

Can someone help me with it? Thank you.

Comment: please create a demo in stackblitz

Comment: Please also share a sample of the property array

Comment: I think i have none. Here is how i call my backend : 
listProperties() {
        return this.http
            .get<any[]>(`${this.gateway.getUrl()}/properties`)
            .map((o) => {
                return o;
            })

Comment: It will be easier to help with information or at least a demo as stated by @brk